# ZIP text files with the NEW Google Drive Android API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

With the old implementation of Google Drive SDK v2, I was zipping text files in order to save upload/download bandwidth. Is it still necessary with the NEW Google Drive Android API? I assume there is some internal compression logic rendering my zipping irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you should not need to do any zipping.  (In fact doing so will cause your text files to be unreadable on the web.)

Comment: Thank you. I will soon be awarded the batch "The King of Questioning the Obvious" :-)